# Can input be asked for inside a method?

Tags: java, input

Would code like this be valid:

```
public class MyProgram {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in)

void someMethod (String input){
//do stuff
}

someMethod (reader.nextLine());
}
```

Would I need to change the parameter `String input` into `System input` or what?
Does this work at all or is it impossible to use nextLine inside a method?
Lastly, would this still apply in the same manner if instead I had `someMethod` be located in an object?

Comment: @alf, yea I did, I got this message when i compiled similar code

An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.7.0). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitStringSwitch(Lower.java:3456)
 at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitSwitch(Lower.java:3357)

Comment: What's the question? You can't do anything in Java unless you're inside a method (or, for completeness, an init block), except initialize variables.

Comment: @EJP I hope that clarifies things

Comment: No, it doesn't 'clarify things', it just repeats the same mistake all over again, for the same reason you were already given. The compiler should already have told you that.

Answer (score 1):

You question show little understanding of the Java programming language.

The signature of someMethod would not change. It is correct. This usage `someMethod (reader.nextLine());` is also correct. `reader.nextLine()` returns a `String` which conforms to the method signature.

It would not change when inside of an object either. It must exist in a class anyway which is an object in a sense.

I would encourage you to read more, learn more about the Java language. Keep experimenting.

Comment: To be honest, your answer does not show a lot of understanding of Java either (-;